# Let $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{P}(n)$ be an antichain of sets of size at most $k \leqslant \frac{n}{2}$. Then $\mathcal{F} \leqslant \binom{n}{k}$.

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to use the LYM inequality and the fact that $\binom{n}{j-1} < \binom{n}{j}$ for $j \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$, but can't quite see how the argument fits together. Any help greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you assuming the union over $\mathcal{F}$  is of size $n$?

Comment: Oops sorry, $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{P}(n)$

Comment: what is the source of the some good questions you have asking recently? Are you taking a course in Extremal combinatorics? Are there some lecture notes concerning this? If so, I would be interested to study it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would argue in the similar way as one arrives at sperner's theorem from LYM Inequality.

LYM Inequality states, $$\sum_{S\in \mathcal{F}}\frac{1}{\binom{n}{|S|}}\le 1$$
where $S$ is a subset in the antichain $\mathcal{F}$. Since, $\binom{n}{k}>\binom{n}{i} \quad \forall \, 1\le i\le k-1$, $$\frac{|\mathcal{F}|}{\binom{n}{k}}\le \sum_{S\in \mathcal{F}}\frac{1}{\binom{n}{|S|}}\le 1$$gives the desired result.